# Having a Spring dependency injection problem

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-data

I have an entity class thus

```
package org.mystuff.dao.entity;

@Entity
public class Result {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private int someStuff;

   public Result(int someStuff) {
       this.someStuff = someStuff;
   }

   public int getSomeStuff() {
       return someStuff;
   }

   public void setSomeStuff(int SomeStuff) {
       this.someStuff = someStuff;
   }
}
```

I have a repository

```
package org.mystuff.dao.repo;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ResultRepository extends JpaRepository<Result, Long> {

    List<Result> getResultByDate(Date date);

}
```

I have a couple of component classes

```
package org.mystuff.dostuff;

@Component
public class UsefulClassA {

    @Autowired
    private ResultRepository resultRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SomethingUseful somethingUseful;

    private Date date;

    public void doStuff() {
        List<Result> resultList = resultRepository.getResultByDate(date);
        // Do something with resultList
    }
}
```

and

```
package org.mystuff.dostuff;

@Component
public class UsefulClassB {

    @Autowired
    private SomethingElseUseful somethingElseUseful;

    private int a;

    public void myMethod(int b)  {
       a = b;
    }

 }
```

I have an test config class

```
package org.mystuff.test.config;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mystuff.dostuff")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.mystuff.dao.repo", entityManagerFactoryRef = "mystuffEntityManagerFactory")
public class AppTestConfig {

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mystuffEntityManagerFactory() {
    
       final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEntityManagerFactoryBean = 
                  new.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       myEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(myDataSource);
       myEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.mystuff.dao.entity")
       return myEntityManagerFactoryBean;    
    }
}
```

And finally, my test class

```
package org.mystuff.test;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppTestConfig.class)
public MyBigTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private UsefulClassB usefulClassB;

    @Before
    public void beforeStuff() {
        // Do some before stuff
    }

    @Test
    public void doATest() {
        usefulClassB.doSomethingUseful();
    }

}
```

I get an exception caused by this

```
Error creating bean with name 'resultRepository': Invocation of init method failed: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: org.mystuff.dao.entity.Result
```

First, why is the container trying to instantiate resultRepository? It's not in the class I'm testing.
Second, why is it saying that Result is not a managed type when it clearly is?

Comment: Please add your import for your classes, need to check for appropriate imports

Comment: Probably you have the wrong `import` in your `ResultRepository` for `Result`. check once or update the post with your imports

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not scanning package containing Entity

```
// your entity package is 
package org.mystuff.dao.entity;

// but you are scanning at `org.mystuff.dostuff`
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mystuff.dostuff")
```

Please, let try to change it to

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mystuff")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve the issues. Choose which suits your conditions.

1. Changing `org.mystuff.dao` to `org.mystuff.dostuff.dao` for both `ResultRepository` and
   `Result`.
2. The other one is chaning the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mystuff.dostuff")` in AppTestConfig to `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mystuff")`

`@ComponentScan` will cause spring to manage only those beans (annotated by @Component, @Service and other @Bean Annotation) which are under the basePackage.
You are giving basePackage as `org.mystuff.dostuff` so the @Bean `Result` and `ResulRepo` are not managed by Spring as they are out of the basePackage supplied.

Comment: I can't do number 1 because it affects a lot of other code. I will add to the question that this has worked previously. Number 2 didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try using @SpringBootTest in Your MyBigTestClass  and also renaming it's package to org.mystuff

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the problem was solved by making UsefulClassA a prototype bean. I assume that since it was a singleton, it could possibly be used in a way that the dependency container didn't know about, so it instantiated it.

Thank you for the answers. They led me to the solution.